# Simulating keypress with onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to simulate the pressing of ESC key (ASCII: 27) when i click on a DIV. I don't want to use any jQuery plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('body').keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                alert('yay 4 escape keys')
            }
            console.log(e);
        });

        var e = $.Event("keydown", {
            keyCode: 27
        });

        $('#escape').click(function() {
            $("body").trigger(e);
        });
    </script>
```

I used this event handler, but it seems not to be working properly.

Comment: On what browser are you testing it? Some browsers for security prevent you from firing keydown-events

Comment: Works on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/GvVDk/ on Chrome and Safari for mac

Comment: i tried it for both Chrome and Firefox in win as well as linux, but the event doesn't triggers. Unable still to figure out why?
Even tried this one

`$('#escape').click(function(){jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : '27' });});`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){  
 var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 27; 

     $('#escape').click(function() {
                $("body").trigger(e);
            });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ could help

```
jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : 27 });
```